# Проблема с установкой свойства css через js

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть на сайте структура `<ul><li><ul><li>`.
То есть в каждом элементе первого списка еще по списку.
Через css меняю свойство top:

```
.well.sidebar-nav>ul>li>ul{
top: 150px;
}
```

Список опускается. Тоже самое делаю через js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = $('.well.sidebar-nav ul');
    var block = $('.well.sidebar-nav ul>li>ul');//Беру список
    var menuItems = menu.find('li');

    menuItems.mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
        $(block).css.top = $(this).offset().top - 268.3999938964844;
        //Меняю списку свойство top
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hovered');
        })
    });});
```

Ничего на самой странице не меняется. Пробовал выводить `$(block).css.top` в консоль, он меняется. Без JS не получится, так как нужно динамически отодвигать этот список. Подскажите пожалуйста, что у меня не так.

Comment: Решил. $(block).css('top', $(this).offset().top - 268.3999938964844);

Answer (score 1):

[.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) в jQuery объекте это **функция**.

В данном случае

```
$(block).css.top = $(this).offset().top - 268.3999938964844;
```

**Функции** добавляется свойство `top`.

Для того, чтобы выполнить функцию, ее нужно вызвать, передав название параметра, и значение:

```
$(block).css('top',$(this).offset().top - 268.3999938964844);
```

Comment: Можете мне помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959689/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B4   ?