# Как убрать функцию паралакс на некоторых див с определённым ид?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой код:

```
// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
var bey = document.getElementById( 'main' );
bey.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);
```

Написал, чтобы паралакс работал если крутишь колесик на мыши, когда курсор на id="main". Хорошо работает.
Но...
Внутри `div id="main"` есть дивы с прокруткой (к примеру div id="scroll").

Как сделать, чтобы функция Паралакса не работала на таких дивах?

***Обновление: Добавил пример!! На второй странице синий квадратик с текстом и прокруткой, но если на него направить мышь и использовать колесико мыши, то прокрутки этого блока (синего) не будет, переезжаем сразу на другую страницу, в зависимости от того, вверх или низ крутим колесик.***

```js
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var isHorizontal = false;
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if(isHorizontal) {
    isHorizontal = false;
    return;
  }
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
var bey = document.getElementById( 'main' );
bey.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}


// SWIPE MODE Rodichev Vladimir
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
    return;
  }


    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    } else {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
/*.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}*/
.background:first-child {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kXq9Qmnj/bgd1.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15vh);
          transform: translateY(-15vh);
}
.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/W14vywqg/photo-1424746219973-8fe3bd07d8e3.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TY0xQ41T/photo-1433840496881-cbd845929862.jpg);
}
/* Set stacking context of slides */
.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.poscustomtext {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.background:nth-child(3) .content-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
    transform: translateY(40vh);
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.background.up-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
}

.background.down-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
article.mario {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
/*article.mario {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  column-width: 100vw;
  column-gap: 5vw;
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}*/
article.mario {
    height: 80vh;
    width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: solid 8px black;
}
article.mario:hover {
    border: solid 8px gold;
}
.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Full Page Parallax Scroll Effect</title>
  
  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
 
.lr2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.container.n1{
    width: 25%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container.n2{
    width: 75%;
}
.bsb {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
  </style>  
</head>

<body>
<div class="lr2">
  <div class="container n1"></div><div class="container n2" id="main">
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-title">Full Page Parallax Effect</p>
      <p class="content-subtitle">Scroll down and up to see the effect!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="bsb" id="scroll">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
</div>
 </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      </div>
  </section>
</div></div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: нужен полнее пример, желательно [mcve] чтобы его прям тут можно было запустить

Comment: @Grundy добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найдите в скрипте добавленный код:

```
document.getElementById("scroll").addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var isHorizontal = false;
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if(isHorizontal) {
    isHorizontal = false;
    return;
  }
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
var bey = document.getElementById( 'main' );
bey.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

document.getElementById("scroll").addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}


// SWIPE MODE Rodichev Vladimir
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
    return;
  }


    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    } else {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
/*.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}*/
.background:first-child {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kXq9Qmnj/bgd1.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15vh);
          transform: translateY(-15vh);
}
.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/W14vywqg/photo-1424746219973-8fe3bd07d8e3.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TY0xQ41T/photo-1433840496881-cbd845929862.jpg);
}
/* Set stacking context of slides */
.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.poscustomtext {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.background:nth-child(3) .content-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
    transform: translateY(40vh);
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.background.up-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
}

.background.down-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
article.mario {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
/*article.mario {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  column-width: 100vw;
  column-gap: 5vw;
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}*/
article.mario {
    height: 80vh;
    width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: solid 8px black;
}
article.mario:hover {
    border: solid 8px gold;
}
.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Full Page Parallax Scroll Effect</title>
  
  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
 
.lr2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.container.n1{
    width: 25%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container.n2{
    width: 75%;
}
.bsb {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
  </style>  
</head>

<body>
<div class="lr2">
  <div class="container n1"></div><div class="container n2" id="main">
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <p class="content-title">Full Page Parallax Effect</p>
      <p class="content-subtitle">Scroll down and up to see the effect!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="bsb" id="scroll">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
</div>
 </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      </div>
  </section>
</div></div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, из примера вашего теперь ясно как. Теперь js, благодаря вам и людям, которые мне помогают, я стал понимать лучше. Спасибо! Доброго вам дня, настроения, здоровья, счастья!!

Comment: document.getElementById("scroll") это по ИД, по классу будет так: document.getElementsByClass("scroll") Правильно?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959792/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @VladimirRodichev вижу, Вам уже объяснили, в чем там дело

Comment: Да.. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B0