# Как убрать функцию паралакс на некоторых дивах с определенным классом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var isHorizontal = false;
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if(isHorizontal) {
    isHorizontal = false;
    return;
  }
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
var bey = document.getElementById( 'main' );
bey.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}


// SWIPE MODE Rodichev Vladimir
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
    return;
  }


    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    } else {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
/*.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}*/
.background:first-child {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kXq9Qmnj/bgd1.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15vh);
          transform: translateY(-15vh);
}
.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/W14vywqg/photo-1424746219973-8fe3bd07d8e3.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TY0xQ41T/photo-1433840496881-cbd845929862.jpg);
}
/* Set stacking context of slides */
.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.poscustomtext {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.background:nth-child(3) .content-wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
    transform: translateY(40vh);
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}
.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.background.up-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
}
.background.up-scroll + .background .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
          transform: translateY(30vh);
}

.background.down-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
          transform: translateY(40vh);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background.down-scroll + .background:not(.down-scroll) .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
          transform: translateY(15vh);
}
article.mario {
    height: 100vh;
    width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(100vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
/*article.mario {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  column-width: 100vw;
  column-gap: 5vw;
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}*/
article.mario {
    height: 80vh;
    width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
    column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
    /* column-gap: 317px; */
    column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: solid 8px black;
}
article.mario:hover {
    border: solid 8px gold;
}
.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.lr2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.container.n1{
    width: 25%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container.n2{
    width: 75%;
}
.bsb {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Full Page Parallax Scroll Effect</title>
  
</head>

<body>
<div class="lr2">
  <div class="container n1"></div><div class="container n2" id="main">
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="bsb" id="scroll">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
</div>
      <p class="content-title">Full Page Parallax Effect</p>
      <p class="content-subtitle">Scroll down and up to see the effect!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="bsb" id="scroll">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
</div>
 </div>
  </section>
  <section class="background">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="bsb" id="scroll">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
</div>
      </div>
  </section>
</div></div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>




</body>

</html>
```

У синих квадратов класс "bsb"
Я пытался так:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bsb").addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересно, вас не смутило, что данный код производит ошибку в консоли?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bsb").addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Функция `getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов. Поэтому `addEventListener` не работает.

Посмотрите пример.

```js
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var isHorizontal = false;
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if (isHorizontal) {
    isHorizontal = false;
    return;
  }
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
var bey = document.getElementById('main');
bey.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}


// SWIPE MODE Rodichev Vladimir
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(yDiffAbs) < offset) {
    return;
  }


  if (yDiff > 0) {
    //Up scroll
    ticking = true;
    if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
      currentSlideNumber--;
    }
    previousItem();
    slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
  } else {
    //Down scroll
    ticking = true;
    if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
      currentSlideNumber++;
      nextItem();
    }
    slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
  }
});

function getTouch(e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}

[...document.querySelectorAll(".bsb")].forEach(el => el.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
  transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}


/*.background:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}*/

.background:first-child {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kXq9Qmnj/bgd1.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15vh);
  transform: translateY(-15vh);
}

.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
  transform: translateY(15vh);
}

.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/W14vywqg/photo-1424746219973-8fe3bd07d8e3.jpg);
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/TY0xQ41T/photo-1433840496881-cbd845929862.jpg);
}


/* Set stacking context of slides */

.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.poscustomtext {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background:nth-child(3) .content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
  transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}

.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
  transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}

.content-title {
  font-size: 12vh;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.background.up-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}

.background.up-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
  transform: translateY(15vh);
}

.background.up-scroll+.background {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 30vh, 0);
}

.background.up-scroll+.background .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30vh);
  transform: translateY(30vh);
}

.background.down-scroll {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -130vh, 0);
}

.background.down-scroll .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40vh);
  transform: translateY(40vh);
}

.background.down-scroll+.background:not(.down-scroll) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}

.background.down-scroll+.background:not(.down-scroll) .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15vh);
  transform: translateY(15vh);
}

article.mario {
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 0px);
  column-width: calc(100vw - 0px);
  column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
  /* column-gap: 317px; */
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 120px;
}


/*article.mario {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  column-width: 100vw;
  column-gap: 5vw;
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
}*/

article.mario {
  height: 80vh;
  width: calc(80vw - 0px);
  column-width: calc(80vw - 0px);
  column-gap: calc(5vw + 0px);
  /* column-gap: 317px; */
  column-rule: 2px dotted #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: solid 8px black;
}

article.mario:hover {
  border: solid 8px gold;
}

.emphase {
  display: block;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.lr2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.container.n1 {
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container.n2 {
  width: 75%;
}

.bsb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Full Page Parallax Scroll Effect</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="lr2">
    <div class="container n1"></div>
    <div class="container n2" id="main">
      <section class="background">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="bsb">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down
            and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up
            to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
          </div>
          <p class="content-title">Full Page Parallax Effect</p>
          <p class="content-subtitle">Scroll down and up to see the effect!</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="background">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="bsb">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down
            and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up
            to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="background">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="bsb">Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down
            and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up
            to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect! Scroll down and up to see the effect! Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Тест тест Scroll down and up to see the effect!
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Нет. я делал попытку сегодня на скорую руку, не обратил внимание на консоль. У меня есть аналогичный пример, там подобный код работает. По этой причине я не задумался об этом, так как консоль спрятана в инспекторе, не на виду, не подумал её проверить. У меня небольшой опыт с js/jq, чтобы писать самостоятельно. Но, да, примеры мне помогают, и уже некоторые вещи я научился делать сам, опыт набирается. И опять же, благодаря таким людям как вы. Спасибо.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev Подобный код `getElementsByClassName("bsb").addEventListener` нигде не будет работать. Проверьте, может там тоже не работает. Консоль лучше всего всегда держать включенной - никогда не знаешь, когда она пригодится)

Comment: В другом коде работает, он там в переменной: $(document).ready(function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
  var i;
  for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }
  ...
  });
});

Comment: Можете ещё, пожалуйста, на таких же дивах сделать так, чтобы не работал свайп?

Comment: Я, надеюсь, что вы сами видите, что приведенный вами код в комментарии ну прям вообще не похож на тот, который в вопросе. Если у вас есть еще вопрос - смело задавайте!

Comment: Спасибо.. Задаю.. вот такой вопрос есть.. новый. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B0